# Bootstrap Carousel speed

Tags: jquery

Pulling my hair out trying to dynamically change the speed of the Carousel.

I want to use a slider to speed up or slow down the interval between slides.

I start at 5000 which I know is <==> 5secs. I have used an interval of 100 so I can see that it works, I will then use the slider value to change the speed. This works out side of the function when the page loads, but not on the event call?

```
$("#myCarousel").carousel({
          interval: 100
        });
```

Help !!

```
$("#ex1").on("slideStop", function(){
         $("#myCarousel").carousel({
          interval: 100
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

> The speed cannot be controlled by the API.

Though you can add CSS `transition` property that changes it.

Comment: use .css({ 'transition-duration': '1s'; }) and change '1s' (speed) dynamically.